# What is the correct Bean's proxyMode for allowing concurrency in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I am building a library based on Spring Framework and I want to allow users invoke Library's methods in parallel.

In my main class I autowire Service class:

```
@Autowired
private ExportListCommand exportList;
```

And that's implementation for Library's method:

```
public ResponseContainer<ExportListResponse> exportList(ExportListOptions options) {
    exportList.setoAuthClient(oAuthClient);
    ResponseContainer<ExportListResponse> result = exportList.executeCommand(options);

    return result;
}
```

`ExportListCommand` is defined as a Bean:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public ExportListCommand exportList() {
    return new ExportListCommand();
}
```

When I as a Library user run 2 exportList's methods in parallel Spring creates only single `ExportListCommand` bean since it autowired only once. But in reality I need 2 independent `ExportListCommand` beans. I also tried to change `@Scope(value="prototype")` to `@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`, but that also does not work as I need: Spring creates `ExportListCommand` bean for each method invocation and I lose `oAuthClient` value since I get new object.

I made it work only with `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.getBean()` approach which I would like to avoid.

What my options are? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to work with a 'factory' object.

There are two primary ways I would consider this from a Spring standpoint.

1. The 'Java' way: Create a factory object that will return instances of `ExportListCommand`

This factory would look something like this:

```
class ExportListCommandFactory {
    ExportListCommand newInstance() {
        return new ExportListCommand();
    }
}
```

and would be used in your method like this:

```
@Autowire
private ExportListCommandFactory commandFactory;

public ResponseContainer<ExportListResponse> exportList(ExportListOptions options) {
    final ExportListCommand exportList = commandFactory.newInstance();
    exportList.setoAuthClient(oAuthClient);
    ResponseContainer<ExportListResponse> result = exportList.executeCommand(options);

    return result;
}
```

Of course, doing this would require that you change your configuration to contain a bean that is an `ExportListCommandFactory` rather than an `ExportListCommand`.

Alternatively, you could consider...

2. The 'Spring' way: Use [`FactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html)

The only thing you should need to do here is, in your main class, `@Autowire` a `FactoryBean<ExportListCommand>` instead of the `ExportListCommand`, and in your method where you need to invoke the method, consult the factory to get your instance.

```
@Autowire
private FactoryBean<ExportListCommand> commandFactory;

public ResponseContainer<ExportListResponse> exportList(ExportListOptions options) {
    final ExportListCommand exportList = commandFactory.getObject();
    exportList.setoAuthClient(oAuthClient);
    ResponseContainer<ExportListResponse> result = exportList.executeCommand(options);

    return result;
}
```

You shouldn't need to change your configuration, as FactoryBean is a special bean that will consult the ApplicationContext/BeanFactory for the instance at each invocation of `getObject()`.

Comment: Many thanks for so well crafted answer. Since `FactoryBean` is an Interface I should implement it, correct? And inside implementation I have pretty much the same choice: call `new ExportListCommand()` which will break all IoC dependency or call `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` again. I have not mentioned, but I have dozen of Commands and I don't want separate Factory for each Command, so Factory should know how to return appropriate Command and I think I can achieve that with Generics. Also, Command depends on related Response bean, so IoC should perform heavy lifting

Comment: You should not need to implement factory bean. Spring recognizes the class and treats it specially. Do it as I wrote and it should work.

Comment: That's strange. Spring gives me: "Field commandFactory in *** required a bean of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean' in your configuration." Do you know what is the default implementation Class for this Interface?